# Can't connect HM10 to Android device

Tags: android, arduino, hm-10

I am currently developing a device that uses a Pro Micro micro-controller, an HM10 ble module (I checked and this isn't a BLE-CC41A), and several Android devices. My issue is the connection between the Android and the HM10. A few days ago the connection between these two worked well and I could send and receive messages between these two. Now the Android can see the HM10 module but for some reason it cannot connect. I have tried several applications such as "nRF Connect", "BLE Scanner", and "MSMBle" all with no results.

All seems fine on the Pro Micro side. With the code I am using I can send AT commands to the HM10. In case you were wondering what code I used for the pro micro:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(9, 8); //RX|TX

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin(9600); // default baud rate
  Serial.println("AT commands: ");
}

void loop(){
  bluetoothCommunication();
  serialCommunication();
}

void serialCommunication() {
  if(Serial.available() >0){ //read from the Serial and print to the HM-10
    bluetooth.write(Serial.read());
  }
}

void bluetoothCommunication(){
  String readStr; //expect a string like wer,qwe rty,123 456,hyre kjhg, or like hello world,who are you?,bye!, 
  while (bluetooth.available() > 0) { //read from the HM-10 and print in the Serial
    delay(10);  //small delay to allow input buffer to fill
    char inChar  = bluetooth.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
    readStr += inChar ;  //makes the string readString
  }
  if (readStr.length() >0) {
    Serial.println(readStr); //prints string to serial port out
  }
}
```

About the BLE HM10 module I pretty much use the default settings but changed the name and password. I also want to note that I tested with three HM10 modules and none can connect to an Android device.

Has anyone had the same issue? Did Android make an update that made HM10 modules unusable?

Comment: UPDATE: I also tested the BLE-CC41A which had the same results